# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at parse

Tags: php, jquery, json

The following JS code snippet:

```
    var data_JSON = {
        input: 'test',
        message: 'Sending...'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'main_php.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_JSON,
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',        
        success: alert(data),       
        error: function (request, status, error) {      
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

And the following associated PHP code (main_php.php):

```
if ($_POST){    
    $vals = array(
        'input'     => $input,
        'message'   => $message
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($vals);        
}
```

Always result error (`error` runs in `$.ajax`), whatever I tried. In the browser's developer console, I could explore the complete length of the **error message**:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at parse (native) at ajaxConvert
>   ([...]/jquery-3.0.0.js:8544:19) at done
>   ([...]/jquery-3.0.0.js:9011:15) at XMLHttpRequest.
>   ([...]/jquery-3.0.0.js:9303:9)

Which is *exactly* the point where the JSON is failed to parse? What is the reason of this error and how can I solve it?

Note: `JSON.stringify` did not work, if that helps anything.

Comment: Is the JSON the only content you return, or does execution of the PHP code continue after the `if` statement? Try checking the exact response value in the console.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there's nothing else in the PHP file to execute, and in the JS file neither. I just want to make a "frame" to build on, currently.

Comment: How are you getting `$input` and `$message` directly ? Shouldn't it be `$_POST['input']` and `$_POST['message']` ?

Comment: `data: data_JSON,` should be `data: JSON.stringify(data_JSON),`

Comment: Could you try another version of jquery. say 2.1.1 and see if the error still persists

Comment: @AdityaParab I told in the original post that it didn't work.

Comment: @roberto06 It has no effect. There's no even a slight change on the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

js:

```
var data_JSON = {
    input: 'test',
    message: 'Sending...'
 };

$.ajax({
  url: 'main_php.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: data_JSON,
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)) ;
  } ,       
  error: function (request, status, error) {      
    alert(error);
  }
});
```

and 
php:

```
if ($_POST){    
    $vals = array(
      'input'     => $input,
      'message'   => $message
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($vals);        
}
```

Comment: **I can't freakin' believe it! This was the problem!** Thank you very much!